# Using a stored procedure with where value in ()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

So, In my stored procedure I have

```
Update Table
Set Table.Value = 2
Where Table.ID In (1,2,3)
```

I call the stored procedure and I want to pass in the 1,2,3.
There is an unknown number of values in this list so I can't just use several variables.

I have tried the following but this doesn't work

```
Declare @IDS Varchar = '1,2,3';

Update Table
Set Table.Value = 2
Where Table.ID In (@IDS)
```

Is there an array type (or similar) in T-SQL that would allow me to pass multiple values in for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Use Dynamic query.

Comment: I'd add to the duplicate answers that [SQL Server 2016 has `STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass either table variable to stored procedures or xml variable. I prefer xml, because it's more elastic.

Example:

```
    GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #tmpProcedure
    @xml xml
AS

    UPDATE tbl SET 
        Value = 2
    FROM table tbl
    WHERE 1 = 1 
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                    FROM @xml.nodes('IdsToUpdate/Id') t(x)
                    WHERE 1 = 1 
                        AND t.x.value('.','int') = tbl.Id
                    )


GO
DECLARE @xml xml =
        '
            <IdsToUpdate>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <Id>14</Id>
                <Id>15</Id>
                <Id>2</Id>
            </IdsToUpdate>
        '
GO

EXEC #tmpProcedure @xml
```

Comment: The code is more *cumbersome* and probably results in a fullt able scan too. With a TVP you'd only need to join the target table with the parameter. You could improve performance if you extracted the IDs and placed them in a table variable. But why do that, when you can just use a table parameter?

Comment: Table parameter require from you to create data type

Comment: Another easy way is to create tmp table before you call your stored procedure. That allow you to use tmp table and it's values within stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, and xml requires that you create and hard-code a schema and query. They also require that you pay attention to avoid a full table scan

Comment: As for the temporary table, why? Is that in any way *easier* than using a table type? Don't forget concurrency issues